# node-js polars List context and row wise compute

Tags: node.js, dataframe, nodejs-polars

I'm trying to use the [nodejs bindings](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/list_context.html) for the [polars](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/introduction.html) library to calculate the results of ranked choice elections in a hypothetical space. I was able to get this working through the python bindings [here](https://gist.github.com/schicks/5ea4085acf6312e0281ec48a103fc1d5) without too much trouble, but it depends on [list context](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/list_context.html) features, specifically `pl.element()`, in order to do some of the calculations. The problem I'm running into is that there does not appear to be an equivalent feature in the nodejs bindings. Is there a different way to talk about the element of a list through the nodejs bindings? Is there a way to do something like this;

```py
lambda loser: pl.col("vote").arr.eval(pl.element().filter(pl.element() != loser)).alias("vote")
```

without using `pl.element()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently JS bindings do not have `pl.element`, but under the hood, it is just an alias for an empty string.

```
loser => pl.col("vote").arr.eval(
    pl.col("").filter(pl.col("").neq(loser))
  ).alias("vote")
```